# Fecthing the data from database in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-5.1

Good day 
I'm facing some errors while trying to fetch data from database

here are my codes

my table name is meeting and I used the formal documentation to write the codes

controllers.php

```
public function meetingdet()
{
    $mretive = \DB::table('meeting')-> $name = $request->input('meetingname');}
```

view

```
    <table border="1"  >
<tr>
<td><b>blah</b> </td>
<td><b>blah</b> </td></tr>
<tr>    
<td>
</td>
<td><li>foreach ($name as $retrive) {
    echo $retrive-> meeting;}
          @endforeach
</li>
</td>
</tr>
     </table>
```

but this what is showing for me

> syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) and whan I remove
>   endforeach it display for me the for each without fetching the data

By the way I'm working on laravel 5.1

Regards

Comment: Your query is wrong. Can you please indicate your model?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the following sample code:

controllers.php

```
//include your model file
use App\model;

public function meetingdet()
{
$meetingData = model::getMeetingData();
$view = array(
              'name'=>$meetingData
            );
return view('test', compact('meetingData'));
}
```

Model.php

```
public static function getMeetingData()
{
    $value=DB::table('meeting')->orderBy('meeting_id', 'asc')->get();
    return $value;
}
```

view.blade.php

```
<table border="1"  >
<tr>
<td><b>blah</b> </td>
<td><b>blah</b> </td></tr>
<tr>    
<td>
</td>
<td>
<ul>
<li>
@foreach ($meetingData as $retrive)
{{{ $retrive->meeting_id }}}
@endforeach
</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you but its still showing for me an error Undefined variable: name

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check now. There are changes in controller file and view file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
  @foreach ($name as $retrive)
    {{ $retrive->meeting }}
  @endforeach
</li>
```

you didn't add @ to foreach..